# How to create a alert message instead of toast

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, toast

I have a problem. I have made an QR code scanner and i when he scan the code he put the result like toast but I want it as Alert Message. Can anyone help?

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.zxing.Result;

    import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
private ZXingScannerView zXingScannerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void scan(View view){
    zXingScannerView =new ZXingScannerView(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(zXingScannerView);
    zXingScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    zXingScannerView.startCamera();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    zXingScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),result.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    zXingScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);

}
}
```

It is the last 4 lines in code.

Comment: Did you mean AlertDialog?

Comment: I have alredy seen that question. And i have tried every answer but i don't know how to insert it in my code to make it functional